# How to use nagios's check_udp for Monitoring ntpd?

Tags: nagios, ntpd

I want monitor my ntpd services and ntpd service is used udp protocol。nagios have a method that is named check_udp,As follows：
[root@localhost]# ./check_udp -H 127.0.0.1 -p 123 
With UDP checks, a send/expect string must be specified.

I want to know how to use check_udp...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest saving yourself some effort and use one of the many NTP nagios plugins like the one below from the official nagios plugins package.

http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_ntp_peer

Comment: :check_ntp_peer -H 192.168.18.105
NTP OK: Offset 0 secs|offset=0.000000s;60.000000;120.000000;What's mean that offset=0.000000s;60.000000;120.000000

Comment: That's the performance data whuich is used for graphing.  http://nagiosplug.sourceforge.net/developer-guidelines.html#AEN201